# Error dynamically updating a table row using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to update the value (views) of a table row using Ajax when an onclick event is called.

The views are updated but the problem is that I can't get the new value of the views to show on that particular table row.

I have to refresh the page to see the updated views value and that's not what I want.

I want it updated dynamically as the button is clicked. This is what I am doing.

```
<table>
@foreach($data as $datum)
<tr>
  <td><span class="view2">{{$datum->views}}</span></td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="bigImg(event)"  value="{{$datum->game_id}}">click</button></td>
 </tr>
@endforeach                                         
</table>
<script>
        function bigImg(event) {
            var game_id = event.target.value;
            var obj = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                type:'POST',
                dataType:'JSON',
                url:'{{url('views')}}',
                data:'game_id='+game_id,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    var data=eval(data);
                    message=data.message;
                    //console.log(message);
                    obj.closest('tr').find(".view2").text(message);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: why do you use eval ?

Comment: Use Datatable to achieve this. That will be much easier and effective